# AlphaAnimation in android

Tags: android, button, parameters

I am implementing an AlphaAnimation in my android project with the below line code, but I am unsure how it works and what goes in the parameters.

```
AlphaAnimation buttonClick = new AlphaAnimation(1F, 0.1F);
```

1. What is the first parameter for and what what values can I put in it?
2. What is the second parameter for and what values can I put in it?
3. Is it possible to have more then 2 parameters?

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AlphaAnimation` is for fading in / out view.

As per [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AlphaAnimation.html#AlphaAnimation%28float,%20float%29)

> Parameters:
>   fromAlpha :   Starting alpha value for the animation, where 1.0 means fully opaque and 0.0 means fully transparent.
>   toAlpha : Ending alpha value for the animation.

So if you use

```
AlphaAnimation buttonClick = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
```

It will mean opacity will be 1 at the end of animation.

Whereas, for fading out image from visible to invisible, you can use

```
AlphaAnimation buttonClick = new AlphaAnimation(1.0f, 0.0f);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: So, the first parameter is for fading out and second for fading in?

Comment: No. First will be opacity of view at start of animation. And second will be opacity of view at end of animation.

Comment: oh ok, what is the max and min number I can have in both parameters?

Comment: It will be 1.0 max and 0.0 min as its written: **where 1.0 means fully opaque and 0.0 means fully transparent.**

Comment: Yes. Get a simple point that its just parameter for opacity at different times.

Comment: thanks for your help. marked your answer as answered!

Comment: btw, is it possible to add more parameters to AlphaAnimation . like shades

Comment: I am not aware about that. I think there are just two constructors for AlphaAnimation. Not more.